# Customizable pop-up in React

Tags: reactjs, popup

How do I create a customizable pop-up with React?(preferred to not use ES6 syntax)

I also wonder if I could use Jquery dialog in React and if so, how do I do it.

Comment: Try [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html). Using jQuery modal is also possible but can be a pain in the back.

Comment: Thank you. I think that would be perfect fit for what I'm trying to do